# How to check the state (uncorrupted) of a BAK file with powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-backups

I'm transferring a BAK file to ~20 target machines and want to validate that the transfer completed and didn't corrupt the BAK files when the transfer is complete.

This is part of a powershell workflow.

I have the following:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = N'\\TARGETMACHINE\F$\backup.bak'" -queryTimeout -verbose 65534
```

Which runs and completes in the same time as a local execution, but I don't get any output through powershell.  I've seen some solutions that write to a text file, but I'd really like to determine whether or not the BAK can be verified from within powershell only if possible - so I can then initiate a retry from the same workflow if it fails.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What if you use [`Get-FileHash`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520872.aspx) before and after the transfer? It doesn't check that it's a valid .bak file but it does (mostly) confirm that the transfer process didn't alter the file.

Comment: Awesome!  I could validate BAK locally and then validate hash after... I like that.

Answer (score 1):

When I test locally, I receive this message from Powershell:

```
VERBOSE: The backup set on file 1 is valid.
```

Perhaps your querytimeout value is misplaced?  Try the command with only -verbose:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = N'\\TARGETMACHINE\F$\backup.bak'" -verbose
```